# Perform a function after union of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, union

I have two tables that I want to union together then perform some math functions on the combined table.

I know how to do the math for each separate table, but throwing in a union table to go off of is out of my league.

Here's the math for one table using column header "UnitsReceived" and "AsnPsUnits"

The other table would have headers: "cUnitsReceived" and "cAsnPsUnits"

```
select VendName,  
  1-abs(((cast(sum(UnitsReceived) as decimal(5,0))) - (cast(sum(AsnPsUnits) as decimal(5,0)))) /(cast(sum(AsnPsUnits) as decimal(5,0)))) as ASNpsAcc
from VenTest2
where ID<20
group by VendName
```

How would I perform this function after the union of two tables?

Comment: You can just use the union as a subquery, i.e., select ... from (your union..) t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the unioned tables into some table object before performing your function. This could be done using:

A [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
with cte as (
    select ID, VALUE from A
    union all
    select ID, VALUE from B
)
select
    *
    ,myfunction(VALUE) as MyFunctionResult
from
    cte
```

A temp table

```
select ID, VALUE into #myTempTable from A
insert into #myTempTable select ID, VALUE from B

select
    *
    ,myfunction(VALUE) as MyFunctionResult
from
    #myTempTable
```

A table variable

```
declare @myTableVariable table (ID int, VALUE decimal)

insert into @myTableVariable
select ID, VALUE from A
union all
select ID, VALUE from B

select
    *
    ,myfunction(VALUE) as MyFunctionResult
from
    @myTableVariable
```

A sub query

```
select
    *
    ,myfunction(VALUE) as MyFunctionResult
from
    (
        select ID, VALUE from A
        union all
        select ID, VALUE from B
    ) mySubQuery
```

Comment: for clarity, do column headers in both tables need to be the same?

Comment: The unioned result will have the column names of the first query. The second query must match the number of columns as the first and they should be compatible types, but they could be named differently

Answer (score 0):

This will help with the subq being the union

```
select VendName,  
  1-abs(((cast(sum(UnitsReceived) as decimal(5,0))) - (cast(sum(AsnPsUnits) as decimal(5,0)))) /(cast(sum(AsnPsUnits) as decimal(5,0)))) as ASNpsAcc
from 
(
select ID, UnitsReceived, AsnPsUnits from VenTest2 where ID<20
union
select ID1, UnitsReceived1, AsnPsUnits1 from VenTest1
)a

group by VendName
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not the way, brothers:

```
select VendName,  
1-abs(((cast(sum(UnitsReceived) as decimal(10,2))) - (cast(sum(AsnPsUnits) as decimal(10,2)))) /(cast(sum(AsnPsUnits) as decimal(10,2)))) as ASNpsAcc

from VenTest2
where ID<10
group by VendName

union

select cVendName,  
1-abs(((cast(sum(cUnitsReceived) as decimal(10,2))) - (cast(sum(casnpsunits) as decimal(10,2)))) /(cast(sum(cAsnPsUnits) as decimal(10,2)))) as ASNpsAcc

from CTest
where id <10
group by cvendname
```

Comment: It would be polite if you edited this answer and properly formatted the code.

Comment: Hi @AndrewNguyen, I don't believe this query will get you the result you are wanting. This will result in two records for the same Vendor Name instead of a summary by Vendor Name

Comment: Hi, @Josh Jay, I checked the math manually and it's good. Also, I am only getting one record for each vendor.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen, are you sure there aren't any instances where you have the same vendor in both tables? If so, you'll end up with two records for that vendor instead of a combined record.

Comment: @JoshJay Yeah you're right there are two instances for some vendors.